# CSS Selector with nth

Tags: css, css-selectors

Please help me to select on this jsfiddle the .url class last three element?

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/eW6S5/135/">CSS</a>
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: this is called pretty url just google it

Comment: It can't be easily done if they're not on the same container

Comment: When asking questions on SO, a fiddle link is fine, but please also post the code here into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
.projects:nth-last-of-type(1) .url , .projects:nth-last-of-type(2) .url , .projects:nth-last-of-type(3) .url{
    background:blue;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/eW6S5/136/

Or even more effective and elegant (by mighty [Itay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1947677/itay)):

```
.projects:nth-last-of-type(-n+3) .url
```

Comment: Or simply `.projects:nth-last-of-type(-n+3) .url`. And anyway he probably wants only the three last `.url` to be colored, not the entire lists.

Comment: @Miki use Itay's solution: `.projects:nth-last-of-type(-n+3) .url`

Comment: Why `:nth-last-of-type()` and not `:nth-last-child()`? Note that combining a class selector with `:nth-last-of-type()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @BoltClock yes ,in this specific case both are usable

Comment: @Cherniv You can edit your answer.

Comment: @Itay no , mate , it is respectively your solution! you're definitely have to post it as an answer!

Comment: Well even if I could (this thread is on hold) I wouldn't have because it's not so different from your solution, only a bit of more efficient.